# $.each Json Data

Tags: jquery, json

im having problems in getting the data inside my json file, it says "undefined". Im trying to get the data from the "key" parameter.

Json Structure:

```
{
   "list":[
      {
         "key":"12 ano",
         "value":"12 ano"
      },
      {
         "key":"12 ano administrativo",
         "value":"12 ano administrativo"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the code:

```
 $.getJSON('what.json', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, value){

         console.log(value.key);
      })
    });
```

Comment: you should iterate over list `$.each(data.list, function(i, value){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate inside `data.list` array

```
$.getJSON('what.json', function(data){
      $.each(data.list, function(i, value){
         console.log(value.key);
      })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate `data.list`, You are getting the error as your JSON doesn't have `key` at top level

```
$.each(data.list, function(i, value){
     console.log(value.key);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use This

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
  alert(val);
  alert(key);
  });
```